# P′′ Language Interpreter/Compiler Resources

Tags: programming, software-recommendation, compilers

According to Wikipedia, [P′′](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2) is a "primitive computer programming language created by Corrado Böhm in 1964 to describe a family of Turing machines."  P′′ contains only four instructions has influenced languages such as Brainfuck.

While a modern interpreter would not be too difficult to write (I'm debating tackling it as a weekend project myself), are there any modern P′′ interpreters?  What about references to the original source code/interpreter from the '60s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original Böhm paper itself is hard to find (see for example [How to prove the structured program theorem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14983/how-to-prove-the-structured-program-theorem)), let alone the original interpreter from the 60s...

However, the [esoteric programming languages wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) has an implementation of a P′′ interpreter in Haskell, on the [P′′ page](https://esolangs.org/wiki/P%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2).

Comment: Is it possible that Böhm never implemented the interpreter? I imagine that as time on a computer was limited and expensive, he never bothered. Afterall, he didn't need to if this was really an academic exercise.

Comment: @Wilson I wondered about that, it could be that the language is just a thought experiment to support the proof of the theorem; reading the original paper might give better insight.

Comment: It would be great to see that original paper.  Is it not available to the public?

Comment: I haven't found it; it's not on the ACM DL at least, and the various citation sites only mention citations of it, not the original. I haven't looked through bitsavers yet...

Comment: It might be available from a [number of libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/icc-bulletin/oclc/2222680). It doesn't seem to be online anywhere or in any currently-available reprint.

Comment: FYI: An English translation of Böhm's PhD is [available here](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/boehmthesis/) and his 2nd paper "_Flow diagrams, Turing Machines and Languages with only Two Formation Rules_" [can be found here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=365646).

Comment: Mmmm Haskell.   Learn both :)